# GridView SelectParameter from code behind

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am using VB.NET webforms.
I have a GridView which brings data from Database when the page loads. The SQLDataSource with Select SQL is as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
     ID="ScopeDataSource" 
     runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLServerConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT [SCO_LINENUM], [SCO_LINETEXT], [SCO_SCOPEID], [SCO_TAB1LINK], [SCO_TAB2LINK], [SCO_TAB3LINK] FROM [SCOPE] WHERE [SCO_SCOPEID] = 'AAAREN02'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My GridView is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView 
     ID="ScopeGrid" 
     runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="ScopeDataSource" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     GridLines="None"
     DataKeyNames="SCO_SCOPEID, SCO_LINENUM">
     <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="SCO_LINENUM" HeaderText="Sr#" SortExpression="SCO_LINENUM">
         <HeaderStyle Height="40px" />
         <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
       </asp:BoundField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="SCO_LINETEXT" HeaderText="Parameter.." SortExpression="SCO_LINETEXT">
         <HeaderStyle Height="40px" />
         <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
       </asp:BoundField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Operator                    Values...........">
       <ItemTemplate>                                                    
         <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownMargin">
           <asp:ListItem>BETWEEN</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>EQUALTO</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>GREATERTHAN</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>LESSTHAN</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RangeStart" Text="None" Width="50px" CssClass="TextBoxMargin"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RangeEnd" Text="None" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>                                                
       <HeaderStyle Height="40px" CssClass="WhiteSpacePreserve" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="SCO_SCOPEID" HeaderText="ScopeID" SortExpression="SCO_SCOPEID">
       <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidegrid" />
       <ItemStyle CssClass="hidegrid" />
       </asp:BoundField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="SCO_TAB1LINK" HeaderText="Tab1" SortExpression="SCO_TAB1LINK" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="SCO_TAB2LINK" HeaderText="Tab2" SortExpression="SCO_TAB2LINK" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="SCO_TAB3LINK" HeaderText="Tab3" SortExpression="SCO_TAB3LINK" />
       </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

As seen in above SQLDataSource, the WHERE clause is hard-coded. I want to make this dynamic by passing a variable to the WHERE clause from code-behind. Also My Page_Load event is empty. So far, since the SQLDataSource WHERE clause is hard-coded in my aspx I can see the data in gridview but I don't know how to send a variable to it from code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work.

Change your select command to

```
 SELECT [SCO_LINENUM], [SCO_LINETEXT], [SCO_SCOPEID], [SCO_TAB1LINK], [SCO_TAB2LINK], [SCO_TAB3LINK] FROM [SCOPE] WHERE [SCO_SCOPEID] = @SCO_SCOPEID
```

Then do like

```
ScopeDataSource.SelectParameters("SCO_SCOPEID").DefaultValue = Your value
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked ! Apart from your suggestion, all I had to do was add a SelectParameter in my SqlDataSource as follows: '<SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="SCO_SCOPEID"/>
                                    </SelectParameters>'